# Link available in two languages: "and" or "or" between the languages?

Tags: translation

I'm translating a Belgian press release from French into English. In the article, there is a link to a Belgian website. The link is not in English, so obviously no use to a monolingual reader of English.

I am adding a few words in brackets before the link to say that it's only available in French and Dutch.

**Should I say "Available in French and Dutch only" or "Available in French or Dutch only"?**

I'm leaning towards "and", but I can't explain why. Just as a native speaker and it "feels" better to me. But I can't find any concrete rules stating which is correct, or are both OK?

Comment: It is _available_ in _both_ languages, so you use _and_. If you would tell someone to follow the link to either the Dutch or French version, you would use _or_: "click here to read the article in Dutch _or_ French".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, French *and* Dutch is correct. The *and* indicates both are available, or implies you can only select on of the two options.